# SSD in external usb 3.0 case not recognized

Tags: usb, ssd, mac-mini, external-disk

- Mac mini 2009
- Intel SSD 330 60 Gb
- IcyBox IB-AC603a USB 3.0

I can't see the SSD in Desktop nor in Disk Utility. I don't know what to do as it is said to be USB 2.0 friendly in case's documentation.

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent. Can you tell us which OS you are running? Is the disk recognsed when connected to other machines?

Comment: Mac OS X 10.7.4. The disk was fully functional in a Windows environment as internal drive. I wasn't able yet to test it, with USB case, on another computer.

Comment: Does the USB port on your Mac mini work if you plug another disk or a keyboard? Is the IcyBox power LED lit? Disk Utility should list it even if the disk filesystem weren't recognized by OS X. Since the disk works as internal drive and assuming the USB port on your Mac mini is OK, I'd say the culprit is either the USB cable or the case. Please test the IcyBox with a different USB cable and with another computer and report back.

Comment: USB ports are working (HUB and mac mini's). The LED is one. I tested it on another computer under Windows 7 and it said that driver for the device is not good. I can't test IcyBox with a different cable because it's not a case with USB cord, it's a sata plug directly connected to usb.

Answer (score 1):

USB 2.0 doesn't provide enough power for the SSD in an enclosure unless you have a case that has a plug where you may add more power (and that's going to be hard to find because USB 3.0 2.5" enclosures normally do not require such extra power and, therefore, will not have the 5v power port).

Or try a powered USB hub between the case and the Mac. That may work.